# Worksheet_Activate not running

Tags: excel, vba

I have large tables in an access db with a function to crunch some numbers (works fine).  It is too slow to open and close the db every time a cell changes in this compensation spreadsheet.  I would like to open the db when the worksheet is opened and close the db when the worksheet is closed.  The error I get is "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set."  Debug takes me to my appsAccess.Run line which works fine when I include the code below to open and close the DB in the actual sub that calls db to perform the calculation (too slow to open/close everytime a number is entered in one of the 91 cells).  My code is:

```
Option Explicit
Public appAccess As Access.Application

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call OpenCompensationDB
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Call CloseCompensationDB
End Sub

Private Sub CloseCompensationDB()
    With appAccess
        .CloseCurrentDatabase
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub OpenCompensationDB()
    With appAccess
        .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\MyPath\Compensation.ACCDB"
        .Visible = False 'Useful for debugging
    End With
End Sub
```

It never appears to run the Activate or Deactivate code.  I have tried using Public, Private, Stop, and Breakpoints with no luck.  There are no issues with the 2013 Trust Center.  I'm at a standstill.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've not set `appAccess` to anything, only declared it.  You need either to use `CreateObject` or `New` to assign an instance of Access to that variable.

Comment: Corrected that problem but still does not work.  Added OpenCompensationDB... 'Set appAccess = New Access.Application'

Comment: "Debug takes me to my appsAccess.Run line" - `appsAccess.Run` seems like a typo? Include `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your modules and it will flag these errors for you.

Comment: Option Explicit was originally set.  It does flag that line as originally stated above, but I don't see the solution.  What am I missing?

Comment: app**s**Access != appAccess  You are using two different variable names.

Comment: Comment error.  The code consistently has 'appAccess'.  There is no instance of appsAccess.  The posted code in the original question is correctly posted, but does not work.

Comment: You should update your question to include your current `OpenCompensationDB` code and add the actual code which is triggering the debugger - ie. your "appsAccess.Run" code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Public appAccess As Access.Application

Private Sub OpenCompensationDB()
    Set appAccess = New Access.Application
    With appAccess
        .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\MyPath\Compensation.ACCDB"
        .Visible = False 'Useful for debugging
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub AutoComp(WritingLevel)
    Select Case WritingLevel
        Case "REP"
            WritingLevelColumn = 10
        Case "SRP"
            WritingLevelColumn = 11
    End Select
    'Debug.Print appAccess.Run("AutoComp", WritingLevel)
    Cells(8, WritingLevelColumn).Value = appAccess.Run("AutoComp", WritingLevel) * Cells(8, _ (WritingLevelColumn - 8)).Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call OpenCompensationDB
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4:H16")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Column
            Case "2"
                WritingLevel = Cells(2, "B").Value
            Case "3"
                WritingLevel = Cells(2, "C").Value
        End Select
        'Debug.Print WritingLevel
        Select Case Target.Row
            Case "8"
                Product = "Auto"
                AutoComp (WritingLevel)
            Case "9"
                Product = "Home"
                HomeComp (WritingLevel)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```